# Redirect after login with Django

Tags: django, redirect

I have a login-page set as my homepage, localhost/mysite. I can login and successfully be redirected to localhost/mysite/mainpage.

The issue is that I can bypass the login simply by just entering the path in the URL, for example; I navigate to the homepage where the login-form is, then I just add /mainpage to localhost/mysite/ which successfully loads localhost/mysite/mainpage.

As you could imagine, this is not great. Does anyone know what I did wrong here?

**My view**

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.info(request, "OK")
                return redirect('/mysite/mainpage')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "NOT OK")

    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'mysite/login.html', {"form":form})
```

**My urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^mainpage/$', views.main),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) on your `main` view. This will redirect to the path set by the [**`LOGIN_URL`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOGIN_URL) to log in the user:

```
# app/views.py

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def index(request):
    # …

@login_required
def main(request):
    # …
```

and in the `settings.py`:

```
# settings.py

# …
LOGIN_URL = 'index'
# …
```

**EDIT**: You can omit the `?next=` query parameter, by setting the `redirect_field_name=…` parameter to `None`:

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name=None)
def main(request):
    # …
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I noticed that I had used this @login_required function before but specified wrong LOGIN_URL. Do you know if you could cleanup the URL received if you try to bypass the login? Would be nice to hide ?next=mainpage. localhost/mysite/?next=/mysite/mainpage/

Comment: @massideux: I think you can set the `REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME` setting to `None` (or the empty string).`